# Backbone/View JQuery Issues - _.extend is not a function, Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

First off, I'm very limited in my knowledge of using Backbone outside of a few tutorials, so thanks in advance to anyone who offers any assistance. I am using JQuery and Backbone to basically set up the page for responsiveness and hidden sidebar navigation.

I am getting *"_.extend is not a function"*, *"Uncaught TypeError: BerlinConnectView is not a function"* and *"Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined*" errors when my page renders AT random (I change nothing and one moment I get one error, reload and get another a minute later).

Hoping someone can look at my code and offer some assistance as I am now days into looking at the same code with no solution.

My file structure is as such:

> js
>
> > Helpers
> >     --helpers.js
> >     Vendor
> >     --backbone.js
> >     --jquery.js
> >     --require.js
> >     --underscore.js
> >     Views
> >     --BerlinConnectView.js
> >     main.js

**BerlinConnectView.js:**

```
//BerlinConnectView.js

define([

  'vendor/jquery',
  'vendor/underscore',
  'vendor/backbone',

  'helpers/helpers'

], function($, _, Backbone, helpers) {

  return Backbone.View.extend({

    'el': 'body',

    'events': {

      'click .scroll a[href*=#]': 'scrollToAnchor',
      'click .slate.dimmed, .thelightbox, .sidebar-container li.internal, .nav-links ul li.internal': 'onLickLightboxLink',
      'click .lightbox .close, .lightbox-container .close-lightbox, .lightbox .lightbox-overlay, .dark-overlay': 'closeLightbox',
      'click .sidebar-control': 'toggleSidebar',
      'click .sidebar .close': 'closeSidebar',
      'mousedown button[data-track]': 'onClickAnylyticsLink',
    },

    'render': function() {

      var self = this;

      // Set high res images if user is on retina
      self.setRetinaInlineImages();

      // Check Scroll Position
      self.checkScrollPosition();

      // Check Scroll Position
      self.outsideLinks();

      // Check if mobile
      self.isMoblie();

      // Creates a sticky menu
      self.stickyMenu();

      //
      self.videoHider();

      // self.checkHash();
    },

    // checkHash:function() {

    //   var self = this;
    //   var hash = window.location.hash.replace('#','');

    //   if(hash.length === 0) return;

    //   self.openLightbox(hash);
    // },

    'videoHider': function() {

      var self = this;

      // setTimeout(function() {
      //   $('.video-hero .logo').addClass('fadeIn');
      // }, 12000);

      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.video-hero').addClass('fadeOut');
      }, 1000);

      $(".video-hero video").bind("ended", function() {
        $('.video-hero').addClass('backgroundAdded');
      });

    },

    'isMoblie':function() {

      var self = this;

      var ismobileDevice = /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());

      if (ismobileDevice)
      {
        $('*').css("background-attachment", "scroll")
        $('.mobile').removeClass("hidden")
        $('.desktop').addClass("hidden")
      }
    },

    'outsideLinks':function() {

      var self = this;

      $(document.links).filter(function() {
          return this.hostname != window.location.hostname;
      }).attr('target', '_blank');
    },

    'trackEvent': function (section, area, action) {

      return _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', section, area, action]);
    },

    'onClickAnylyticsLink':function (ev) {

      var self = this;
      var $target = $(ev.target);

      if (ev.target.tagName !== 'A') {
        $target = $target.closest('a');
      }

      var href = $target.attr('href');
      var parts = $target.attr('data-track').split(':');

      self.trackEvent(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]);
    },

    'toggleSidebar': function () {

      var self = this;
      var $body = $('body');

      $body.toggleClass('active');

      // document.location.hash = '!';

    },

    'closeSidebar': function () {

      var self = this;
      var $body = $('body');

      $body.removeClass('active');

      // document.location.hash = '!';

    },

    'stickyMenu': function () {

      var self = this;
      var $header = $(".menu"),
      $clone = $header.before($header.clone().addClass("clone"));

      $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        var fromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var height = $('.hero, .sub-hero, .video-hero').height();
        $(".menu.clone").toggleClass("down", (fromTop > height));
      });
    },

    'onLickLightboxLink': function (ev) {

      var self = this;
      var $target = $(ev.target);

      if (!$target.hasClass('slate, thelightbox, sidebar-container li.internal, nav-links ul li ')) {
        $target = $target.closest('.slate, .thelightbox, .sidebar-container li.internal , .nav-links ul li');
      }

      var elementId = $target.attr('id');

      self.openLightbox(elementId);
    },

    openLightbox: function(id) {

      // document.location.hash = '!';

      $('.lightbox.' + id).removeClass('hidden');
      $('.dark-overlay').removeClass('hideme');
      $('.lightbox .lightbox-overlay').removeClass('hidden');
      $('body').css("overflow", "hidden");

      // window.location.hash = id;
    },

    'closeLightbox': function () {

      var self = this;
      var $lightbox = $('.lightbox');

      $lightbox.addClass('hide');
      $('.dark-overlay').addClass('hide');
      $('body').css("overflow", "auto");

      setTimeout(function() {
        $lightbox.addClass('hidden');
        $('.dark-overlay').addClass('hideme');
        $lightbox.removeClass('hide');
        $('.dark-overlay').removeClass('hide');
      }, 500);

      // document.location.hash = '!';
    },

    'setRetinaInlineImages': function () {

      var self = this;
      var $retinaImages = self.$('img.retina-image, img.col-image');

      if (window.devicePixelRatio > 1) {
        $retinaImages.each(function() {
          var src = $(this).attr('src');
          if (src) {
            src = src.replace(/(\.)(jpg|png)($|\?)/, '@2x.$2');
            $(this).attr('src', src);
          }
        });
      }
    },

    'scrollToAnchor': function(ev) {

      var self = this;
      var hash = $(ev.target).closest('a').attr('href');

      var $anchor = $(hash);

      if($anchor.length) {

        ev.preventDefault();
        self.$el.animate({scrollTop:$anchor.offset().top}, 500, function () {

          window.location.hash = hash;
        });
      }
    },

    'checkScrollPosition': function() {

      var self = this;

      function checkPosition () {

        var position = $(window).scrollTop();

        var windowHeight = $(window).height();

        var documentHeight = $(document).height();

        var height = $('.hero').height();

        var footerHeight = $('footer').height();

        Backbone.Events.trigger('scroll', position);

        if (position + windowHeight == documentHeight) {
          $(".menu.clone").toggleClass("down");
          $("body").removeClass('active');
        }

      }

      throttledPositionCheck = _.throttle(checkPosition, 250);

      $(window).on('scroll', throttledPositionCheck);
    }
  });
});
```

**Main.js**

```
//main.js

 require([

'vendor/jquery',
'vendor/underscore',
'vendor/backbone',
'views/BerlinConnectView'

], function($, _, Backbone, BerlinConnectView) {

var berlinConnectView = new BerlinConnectView();
berlinConnectView.render();
});
```

**Index.html**

```
<head>
<!--Header Content
...................
...................
...................
-->
  <!-- Scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/vendor/require.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.require = requirejs.config({
      'baseUrl': '/js',
      'context': 'bc'
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.js"></script>


  <!-- Google Analytics
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-82811-13']);
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'myberlinconnect.de']);
    _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
      var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
      ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
  </script>
  -->

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="bc" data-requiremodule="vendor/jquery" src="/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="bc" data-requiremodule="vendor/underscore" src="/js/vendor/underscore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="bc" data-requiremodule="vendor/backbone" src="/js/vendor/backbone.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="bc" data-requiremodule="views/BerlinConnectView" src="/js/views/BerlinConnectView.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="bc" data-requiremodule="helpers/helpers" src="/js/helpers/helpers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/22/2/common.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/22/2/util.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/22/2/stats.js"></script>


</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this can happen depending on how you use `require` to load scripts. `require` will load files asynchronously whenever possible, unless you define `dependencies`.

Your code as written seems to be running into race conditions, in that your vendor libraries are not being loaded before your application code executes.

You can use use `require.config` to define `dependencies` and load vendor libraries synchronously.

In your **main.js**:

```
// main.js
require.config({
    // shim allows us to configure dependencies for scripts 
    // that do not call define() to register a module 
    // e.g. vendor libs, like jQuery, underscore, Backbone, etc...
    shim: {
        backbone: {
            deps: ['jquery', 'underscore'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        }    
    },
    paths: {
        // vendor libs
        jquery:     'vendor/jquery',
        underscore: 'vendor/underscore',
        backbone:   'vendor/backbone'
    }
});

require([
    'backbone',
    'views/BerlinConnectView'
], function( Backbone, BerlinConnectView ) {
    // at this point, $, _, and Backbone are already loaded and 
    // available within the `window` object
    var berlinConnectView = new BerlinConnectView();
    berlinConnectView.render();
});
```

In your **BerlinConnectView.js**:

```
define([
    'helpers/helpers',
], function(helpers) {
    // at this point window.Backbone should exist
    // so you should be able to refer to it globally
    return Backbone.View.extend({
        'el': 'body',
        // ...
    // ...
});
```

Comment: This definitely would explain why the random errors would occur. I figured code was executing depending on which js page loaded first. I made the changes, but now am getting an "require.config is not a function" error. I wonder if this is due to the way my scripts are being called at my index.html file (really header.php in wordpress). I've included the script portion of my header on my original post, I played around with defining the base for requirejs but nothing good came of any changes. Any ideas what is now causing the require.config not to be recognized as a function?

Answer (score 0):

After @jiminikiz help I was able to realize that I was calling dependencies both in my HTML and in the main.js. I removed the HTML calls so that my scripts looked as such:

**index.html**

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/vendor/require.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.require = requirejs.config({
      'baseUrl': '/js',
      'context': 'bc'
    });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.js"></script>
```

After removing calls to dependencies elsewhere the code executed correctly with no errors.

Thanks for the point in the right direction @jiminikiz!